# Meteor, SimpleSchema, meteor-collection2 - Adding to array

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I have defined my filed and shema as:

```
storageArticles:
{
  type: Array,
  autoValue: function() {
    return [];
  },
  label: 'Articless added to storage.',
},
'storageArticles.$': {
  type: String
}
```

When I try to update this field by using (in my server side method):

```
Storages.update(storageId , {$set: { "storageArticles" : articleId }});
```

Everything goes OK, but data is no added to Array.

Can you give me some guidance to solve this.

**EDIT**

Edit adds more details on this question, maybe here is my mistake.

```
'articles.articleAddToStorage': function articleAddToStorage(storageId,articleId) {
    check(storageId, String);
    check(articleId, String);

    try {

      Articles.update(articleId, {  $set: {articleAssignedToStorage:true}});
      Storages.update(storageId , {$addToSet: { "storageArticles" : articleId }});

    } catch (exception) {
      handleMethodException(exception);
    }
  }

handleAddToStorage()
  {

    const articleId = this.props.articleId;
    const storageId = this.state.storageId;
    const history = this.props.history;

    if(storageId!="")
    {

      Meteor.call('articles.articleAddToStorage', storageId,articleId, (error) => {

        if (error) {
          Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger');
        } else {

          Bert.alert("Article assigned to storage", 'success');

        }
      });
    }
    else {
    Bert.alert("Plese select storage", 'warning');

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using the field set operator

With the line

```
Storages.update(storageId , {$set: { "storageArticles" : articleId }});
```

you basically try to [set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) a string value (articleId) to a field that is defined as an array of strings.

This would only make sense if you set an array of values to `storageArticles` (thus overriding the complete field):

```
Storages.update(storageId , {$set: { "storageArticles" : [articleId] }});
```

#### Using array update operators

If you want to push or pull values, you may look for the [mongo array update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) (listing some examples here):

> $addToSet Adds elements to an array only if they do not already exist
>   in the set.

```
Storages.update(storageId , {$addToSet: { "storageArticles" : articleId }});
```

> $pop  Removes the first or last item of an array.

```
Storages.update(storageId , { $pop : 1 });
```

> $pull Removes all array elements that match a specified query.

```
Storages.update(storageId , {$pull: { "storageArticles" : articleId }});
```

> $push Adds an item to an array.

```
Storages.update(storageId , {$push: { "storageArticles" : articleId }});
```

> $pullAll  Removes all matching values from an array.

```
Storages.update(storageId , {$pullAll: { "storageArticles" : [articleId1, articleId2] }});
```

Comment: By using Storages.update(storageId , {$addToSet: { "storageArticles" : articleId }}); I get this error: update failed: Error: Storage articles must be of type String

Comment: On a new or an existing doc? I ask because when you try it on the doc where you previously set the field to an articleId, which is a string, the field is not an array anymore. Using an array update method on it will then likely result in that error.

Comment: I have open Robo 3T and I see that type of storageArticles is Array, but when I try to update it it does not work, I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: Try removing the `autoValue` - you don't need to initialize an empty array.

Comment: Thank You @MichelFloyd, this together with Mr. Jankapunkt suggestion solved the issue.